# Volatile variable reads : Who performs the taks JVM or OS?

Tags: java, jvm

when volatile variable reads, the cache/registers data is flushed and a read is done from RAM(main memory) directly - this is called read barrier.

Qs
Who performs the above task, JVM or OS ?
These cache/registers are part of stack/heap ?

---

One more question:
Heap is managed by JVM(which is managed by OS) ?
Java Stacks are managed by OS(and not by JMV) ?

Comment: One question per post

Comment: Both your guesses are wrong. Memory consistency between threads has to be handled at the CPU level, the JVM uses either the OS functions for this or the instructions directly to implement the semantics of its memory model. It's not an either/or thing, it's just different layers of abstraction.

Comment: @ Agree, but these are one/few lines as a Ques and answer

Comment: @Naroji Isn't that a disagreement? Also, Sami is right. Omnibus questions, however simple, are bad. If your questions are oneliners it probably means the questions themselves are low quality. (E.g. you should've googled.)

Comment: ok, i m dividing it into two diff questions

Answer (score 1):

How this is done is of course dependent on the machine's hardware. On some machines, it may also be dependent on the operating system. But i believe that all common processors these days have instructions available to user-mode code which can be used to achieve memory consistency; the OS does not need to be involved.

For the gory details explained far better than i can, see the section on 'Memory Barriers' in [The JSR-133 Cookbook for Compiler Writers](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html).

It is worth clarifying that the operation that is needed is (usually) not actually a flush to main memory or read from main memory. It is enough to make sure that the caches of all processor cores are consistent with one another, even if they are not yet consistent with main memory. This is generally much easier to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM is responsible for implementing the language specifications (including the memory model which defines how volatile variables work).

As its name indicates, the JVM  is a virtual environment which abstracts the actual environment (OS/cpu) away so that the developer does not need to care about where the program is running to write correct code.

In practice, the JVM runs on an OS/cpu and uses the appropriate commands of the OS/cpu to execute a program, for example by issuing memory barriers.